# hsql hibernate dialect for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hsqldb

I use hibernate to manage some of the classes in my project. MySQL 5.5 is the underlying RDMS.

So for regular operations i use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect as the hibernate dialect.

But for unit testing i am using hsql 1.8.0.8 and i use org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect as a dialect for testing.

This was not a problem until one of the developers in my team changed a "varchar" column to "mediumtext".

Now i cannot use nether HSQLDialect nor MySQL5InnoDBDialect for unit tests.

I tried writing my own dialect which extends from HSQLDialect and registering the type as

```
registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, 16777215, "mediumtext" );
```

in the constructor, but this does not seem to work.

The custom dialect i wrote is as follows

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect;

public class HSqlMySqlDialect extends HSQLDialect{
     public HSqlMySqlDialect() {
            super();
            registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, "mediumtext" );
     }

}
```

My test hibernate.cfg.xml looks as below

```
<property name="dialect">com.alcatel.util.hibernate.HSqlMySqlDialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB</property>
```

the error i get when ibernate sessionfactory is started is as below

```
ERROR [SchemaExport] Wrong data type: MEDIUMTEXT in statement [create table TABLE_NAME (ID bigint not null, VALUE mediumtext]
```

So it looks like the dialect is not used when creating tables.

Is there a way around?

Comment: The problem is that org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration#buildSessionFactory() does not use the dialect unlike other methods in the class.
See http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.0.Final/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.java#Configuration.buildSessionFactory%28%29

So looks like no way out.

Comment: Have a look: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.0.CR2/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java#MySQLDialect , mediumtext is being commented. Should look out for why.

Comment: Dialect is being used: Just took out logs from a hibernate sample application start-up.  

**INFO: JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.22 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )**

**Mar 29, 2013 2:44:56 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>**

**INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect**

Comment: Ok, When you say application startup do you mean when sesssion factory is built?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register a varchartype as follows

```
registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, 16777215 , "mediumtext" );
```

you are actually saying all varchars with size <=16777215 will be registered as mediumtext, not the other way round. So the idea of changing column annotations is wrong. Moreover ne should not push DB specific stuff up to hibernate.

So the solution for me was to use varchar() itself in hibernate annotations, but convert them to whatever type i need via a custom dialect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be not to set the "dialect" property, and let Hibernate auto-detect the correct dialect at run time.

Comment: I have tried this, this does not work either.
Hibernate would detect HSQL to be the DB and would use HSQLDialect and the below problem will rise again.
    ERROR [SchemaExport] Wrong data type: MEDIUMTEXT in statement [create table TABLE_NAME (ID bigint not null, VALUE mediumtext]

Answer (score 0):

You can use HSQLDB 2.x and define a type for MEDIUMTEXT. For example:

CREATE TYPE MEDIUMTEXT AS VARCHAR(100000)

HSQLDB 2.x has a MySQL syntax compatibility mode that currently supports TEXT and CTEXT type definitions. MEDIUMTEXT may be supported in the next release.

There is a single Hibernate dialect for versions 1.8 and 2.x. You should be able to define the MEDIUMTEXT type as LONGVARCHAR in a dialect subclass.

registerColumnType( Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar" );

Comment: Yes, HSQLDB 2.x versions do have support for MEDIUMTEXT etx, 
but my problem is with hibernate dialect.
Is there a hibernate dialect in hibernate that can understand "MEDIUMTEXT" from *.hbm.xml files?, say org.hibernate.dialect.HSQL2xDialect or so?. I am using hibernate 3.6.